# How Can I check that user set phone call for 'Always Ask', SIM 1 and SIM 2 in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How Can I check that user set phone call for 'Always Ask', SIM 1 and SIM 2 in react native

I'm expecting that the code gives me true if user select the 'Always Ask' for phone call and return false if 'Always Ask' not selected

Comment: how does the `user set phone call for 'Always Ask', SIM 1 and SIM 2 in react native`?

Comment: As I have the Dual Sim mobile phone and I set 'Always Ask' to select Sim whenever I call my contact, So I want that user can set Always Ask to Sim 1 or Sim 2 in react native, because I'm building a emergency app in which user press the and do some various things in and one of thing is phone call